# How to include dynamic constraints in Linear Optimization with PuLP in python?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I have been working on a linear optimization problem using the PuLP library. How can I include this dynamic constraint in my code?

[snapshot of excel example with terms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeKj9.png)

I need to minimize VaR 1D of the portfolio (-19391.8) formed by the weighted sum of A and B - Objective function

At the same time, VaR10D of of portfolio should be reduced by the target given (-39100 to -29100). 
ow, the catch as you can see is that Var10d and Var1d of the portfolio are the second smallest value in the column of 'Total'. Now, I need to a constraint to add in code that the Var10d should be reduced by 10000 (i.e. to -29100), but at the same time, it should also be the second smallest value in the total column calculated by the weighted sum of 'A' and 'B' on every day.

Thus, I need optimal weights that can 1. minimize Var1d (while it is the second smallest in 'Total' column of Var10d), 2. reduce Var10d by 10000 (i.e. to -29100)(while it is the second smallest in 'Total' column of Var1d).

Answer (score 0):

Min -8000 * x1 - 15000 * x2 + target

I don't get your constraints, because the numbers just seem to be other values for the coefficients in the objective-function.

So I can't see a reason why your "program" not just set x1, x2 = 0, there is nothing to calculate, because there are no constraints..

If you want your objective-value in a specific range you could add:
coeff * x1 + coeff * x2 <= (>=) value
And then if you want to change the right side value, you could run the program again after the first cycle and so on..